# Two edit forms in a single page not retaining values in one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two forms in my view. But when the page loads only the second form is displaying values for editing . If second form do not have any values from the table for editing ,then the first form retains values. I have a resultsController which reads the value from two different component tables and sets these values to the forms in the view. The two forms have separate submit buttons which submits the values after editing to their corresponding component tables. Submission is working fine. I am using ajax submission with cakePhp 2.5.3 . The two forms have unique ids 'Mtp01CompoAddForm' and 'Mtp02CompoAddForm'.  The blank form is retaining value after I make a submission. The relevant part of the code is as follows:

Mtp01CompoAddForm:

```
           echo $this->Form->create('Mtp01Compo', array('action' => 'add'));
           echo $this->Form->input('id1',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$id1));
           $options = array('0' => 'Low Activity ', '1' => 'Medium Activity' , '2' => 'High Activity','3' => 'Extreme Activity');
           echo $this->Form->input('mtpResult_id', array('type' => 'hidden','value'=>$mtpResult_id));
           echo $this->Form->input('q1',array('type'=>'radio','options'=>$options,'required'=>'required'));
           echo $this->Form->input('q2',array('type'=>'radio','options'=>$options,'required'=>'required'));
           echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array('title' => 'Submit'));

           $data = $this->Js->get('#Mtp01CompoAddForm')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
           $this->Js->get('#Mtp01CompoAddForm')->event(
                          'submit',
                          $this->Js->request(
                            array('controller'=>'Mtp01Compos','action' => 'add'),
                            array(
                                    'method'=>'POST',
                                    'data' => $data,
                                    'async' => true,
                                    'dataExpression'=>true,
                                  )
                            )
                        );
           echo $this->Form->end();
           echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('inline' => 'true'));
           echo $this->fetch('script');


        ?>
```

Mtp02CompoAddForm is similar with different number of radio buttons and it submit to Mtp02Compos.
In my controller I have,

```
            $this->Mtp01Compo->id=$id1;
            $this->request->data = $this->Mtp01Compo->read();
            $this->Mtp02Compo->id=$id2;
            $this->request->data = $this->Mtp02Compo->read();
            $this->set(array('mtpResult_id'=>$mtpResult_id));
```

Comment: i can't see where you create the forms in the controller ??

Comment: This is happening because you are overwriting $this->request->data. Try $this->request->data[] = $this->Mtp02Compo->read();

Comment: Thanks you guys for your reply! @andtxr: Thank you for pointing out the problem for me. I tried using `$this->request->data[]` but it does not seem working. I think I should try setting the individual values for all the variables instead of using read(). Is there any other way around?